# Reduce the file size (quality) of a BitmapImage (without resizing it)

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I can't find a way to reduce the **file size** of an image.
I started from a StorageFile I got using the FilePicker, then I resized it using the WriteableBitmap class, and now I want to reduce the file of my image.

This is the part of my code that isn't working:

```
BitmapDecoder compressDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
PixelDataProvider compressionData = await compressDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
byte[] compressionBytes = compressionData.DetachPixelData();

//Set target image quality
BitmapPropertySet propertySet = new BitmapPropertySet();
BitmapTypedValue qualityValue = new BitmapTypedValue(0.5, PropertyType.Single);
propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue);

imageStream.Seek(0);
BitmapEncoder compressionEncoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, imageStream, propertySet);
compressionEncoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, compressDecoder.PixelWidth, compressDecoder.PixelHeight, compressDecoder.DpiX, compressDecoder.DpiY, compressionBytes);
await compressionEncoder.FlushAsync();
```

The problem is that even if I try to set the qualityValue to 0.5 or less, I can see the image loosing quality (of course), but the file size remains exactly the same.
How's that even possible?

Actually, if I set the quality to 1.0, the file size almost doubles, it I turn it down to like 0.5 the file size remains the same (even if the image has a worse quality) and then if I keep turning it down the file size doesn't change.
If this makes sense, I can't see how :/

Am I missing something here? Is there another way to compress an image?
I mean, I just want my stream not to exceed a fixed maximum lenght, so I want to keep decreasing the quality until I reach the right balance.

Thank you for your help!
Sergio

Comment: It would probably help if you actually *use* the qualityValue variable.  Take a break, pop a bear, kiss the girl, have a sleep, you'll figure it out tomorrow.

Comment: Yup, I edited my code right now, I forgot that when pasting the code inside the question.
It was present when I tried running it though :)
In fact I can see the image loose quality, but as I said the file size is always the same no matter what.

Comment: you can use this API:
https://tinypng.com/
you can send the image and get it back in the same quality but smaller
size (Bytes). it's free up to 500 pics a month and they have API you can use inside your code.
I'm using it and it's great

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for an offline method to do the compression :)

Comment: What was the original image quality? How big was the file to begin with? Your code looks fine. If it was already .5 then recompressing it at higher qualities would increase the file size while reducing image quality slightly. Recompressing again at .5 will maintain the file size but reduce the image quality further. Turning it down lower may run into diminished returns with respect to file size.

Comment: Hello, I started with a 2000*3552 image that was 5.0MB in size. I turned it into a WriteableBitmap and resized it to 563*1000: the file size dropped to 223.6KB. Now, I'd like the resized image to have a maximum size of 200KB. When I used that code to compress it, setting the quality at 1.0 raised the file size to ~420KB, a quality of 0.5 and lower didn't change the file size at all (even if the visual quality was worse).
Is there another way or another class I should use to compress a jpg image? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I just discovered that if I compress the image *before* resizing it the final file size does drop. I took that 5.0MB file and compress it with a quality of 0.3: the size went down to 428KB. When I resized it, the size dropped to 195KB. Why does it only work if I compress it before resizing it? Is there a way to compress the final resized image?

Comment: If you are using filepicker already, use their convert api to compress, resize etc. https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file_processing/image_conversion/image